# Why is SI-unit of density $\frac{\rm kg}{\rm m^3}$?

Tags: conventions, density, si-units, metrology

The CGS unit of Density is: $$\frac{\rm g}{\rm cm^3}$$

Then how can the SI or MKS unit of density be:
$$\frac{\rm kg}{\rm m^3}$$

Shouldn't it be:
$$\frac{\rm kg}{\rm dm^3}$$

Comment: Please explain your reasoning. Why should it be that?

Comment: I thought dividing g and cm^3 by thousand in g/cm^3 should result in kg/dm^3 but yeah it was a pretty stupid question. Should've thought about it before posting the question here. Sorry.

Comment: @Sebastiano, I am the user and saying that the question I asked is pretty dumb in hindsight. I think you misinterpreted who the user is. Anyways, I really respect the way you reacted. Very kind of you.

Comment: @Jeeshaan Oh excuse me very much I have misunderstood. I see that I am very tired. But the concept remain :-). All the best....and however I have voted you :-)

Comment: \begin{align*}
&\frac{g}{cm^3}=\frac{10^{-3}~kg}{(10^{-2})^3~m^3}=1000\frac{kg}{m^3}\\
&\frac{g}{cm^3}=\frac{10^{-3}~kg}{(10^{-1})^3~dm^3}=\frac{kg}{dm^3}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All three versions are fine. Some are just named specifically. You seem to have the misconception that offsets in the numerator and denominator during unit conversions must "balance" each other out - but there is no such requirement.

$$20\;\mathrm{\frac{g}{cm^3}}=\quad0.020\;\mathrm{\frac{kg}{cm^3}}=\quad 20\,000\;\mathrm{\frac{kg}{m^3}}=\quad20\;\mathrm{\frac{kg}{dm^3}}$$

A kilogram is a thousand times a gram while a cubic-metre is a million times a cubic-centimetre. Shifting from $\mathrm g$ to $\mathrm{kg}$ in the numerator thus reduced the value by $1000$ whereas shifting from $\mathrm{cm^3}$ to $\mathrm{m^3}$ in the denominator increases the value by $1\,000\,000$. In total, a value increase by a factor of a thousand when converting from $\mathrm{g/cm^3}$ to $\mathrm{kg/m^3}$.

**All** these units shown above are SI units by the way. An SI unit is (traditionally) any unit made solely of those from the fundamental set: seconds, metres, kilograms, Kelvin, amps, moles and candella, possibly adjusted by prefixes.

- The first is furthermore sometimes referred to as a **CGS** unit (centimetre-gram-second)
- The third one is what we (in the past) called the SI **base** unit and is also sometimes referred to as a **MKS** unit (metre-kilogram-second).

Non-SI units would on the other hand be something like for instance pounds-per-gallon:

$$20\;\mathrm{\frac{g}{cm^3}}=0.167\;\mathrm{\frac{lb}{gal}}$$

Answer (score 7):

The [**MKS** system of units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MKS_system_of_units) is based on **m**eter, **k**ilogram and **s**econd
(hence its name).
Therefore the natural unit for density in this system is kg/m$^3$.

Comment: Very nice the hat :-)

Answer (score 3):

It is true that 1 g/cm$^3$ equals 1 kg/dm$^3$. However there is no reason why the density unit in both systems should express the same quantity. It is quite acceptable, though impractical, that the density of water is 0.001 in mksi units.